# Generate <p> for each element of an array

Tags: node.js

I am trying to generate a

for each element into an array, so that I can display this in a list, I have tried many ways, such as `join()`, `forEach()` and others but I did not succeed.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    db.db()
     .collection("notes")
     .find()
     .toArray(function(e, d) {
       let items = d
     items.forEach(item => {console.log(item)})

     res.end(`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <title>Server</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1> Server running! </h1>
    <ul>
    <p>${JSON.stringify(items.join('</br>'))}</p>
    </ul>
    </body>
    </html>`);
    db.close();
  });
```

});

I would like that every array component, that looks like this:
`{ _id: 5c3f7c25ae62eb0741735d6b,text: '2019-01-16 19:47:01',title: 'Live from an IOT device!' }`
will be displayed in a page in a list, that is why I am trying to add a `</br>`, right not if i use the `join()` function, it works, but array elements are displayed as objects and I cannot read the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `join` method will return a string, so it'll call `toString()` on all its elements. Since the elements here are objects, calling `toString()` on them will convert them to the string `[object Object]`. What you should be doing is mapping the array with JSON.stringify first, *then* joining the result:

```
items = items.map(JSON.stringify);
let output = items.join('<br />');
```

Comment: I was exactly looking for this! I knew there was something wrong with calling `toString()`. Thanks a lot!